# Unable to inflate CollapsingToolbarLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am creating an effect something like Parallax effect to Actionbar. What I am doing is something like this.

[image]

As you can see when the list is scrolled up, action bar is collapsed completely. I am using collapsing toolbar layout and I am following this link, https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout. But when I start my activity, it is giving me error.

This is my full xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tab_indicator_height"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"

            android:id="@+id/main_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
           android:id="@+id/main_view_pager"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   </LinearLayout>

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@android:color/white"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_behavior="shy"
        android:id="@+id/main_bottombar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the fatal error I got when activity is launched

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                         Process: com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport, PID:
>   11556
>                                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport/com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17:
>   Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
>                                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17:
>   Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V in class
>   Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport-2/base.apk)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:663)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:197)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:132)
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Have you added design library in dependencies?

Comment: Already asked ... Did you tried any of available solutions?

Comment: This is interesting. Which API are you testing on? It should work without contentScrim anyway.

Comment: Design library is 25. I am testing on Nexus 5 with android version 6.

Comment: I tried on other solutions. I did even re-copied with old question about collapsing toolbar layout. @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

Comment: I even tried removing bottombar. Not just working.

Comment: Not working.Cannot inflate that layout. :(

Comment: I tried without contentScrim. It is not working. @natario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:id="@+id/main_appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="40dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"

        android:id="@+id/main_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/main_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Woks just fine in my Moto X.

All I did was removing this line: app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"

and tools:context=".MainActivity"

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.hinovamobile.deletethis"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

}
```

Please try this code and tell me if it works for you. Or try yours in another phone.

Comment: I could inflate the layout finally. But action bar and tab layout is completely removed. Not displayed in screen at all. Why please? :(

Comment: Can you post a picture of the screen?

Comment: I get it working because of your answer. The only thing I need to do is to install this in grandle- compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just a missing dependency. It's nice its working =]